# String encoding problem on PdoStatement->bindParam()?

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, pdo, request

I'm trying to perform a simple `SELECT` statement from a string taken from a `$_REQUEST` var but it seem my PDO statement doesn't like the string format, why?

My `$_REQUEST` var contains a string like `Hello+World`, so I need to replace `+` with whitespaces to do my `SELECT` statement correctly.

```
// the data returned is Hello+World
$phrase = str_replace ("+", " ", $_REQUEST["my_data"]);

$phrase_select = $connection->prepare ("SELECT data_field FROM my_table WHERE phrase = ':phrase'");
$phrase_select->bindParam (":phrase", $phrase, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$phrase_select->execute ();
$data_field = $phrase_select->fetchColumn (); // return nothing
```

If I make a `SELECT` manually with a string "`Hello+World`", it works without problems, but if I do it with `$_REQUEST["my_data"]` it won't work, where I'm wrong?
If I print `$_REQUEST["my_data"]` it return exactly `Hello+World`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to add the '..' around your bound param, pdo will do that for you

Comment: thank you! I'll need more practice to understand clearly PDO class